# How make updatedb ignore ~ backup files

Tags: updatedb

updatedb has options to exclude names.

But how get it to exclude by part of a name - eg. the pattern *~

?

Comment: In VMs with centralized storage, I advise not doing updatedb at all.

Comment: Which implementation of updatedb? There are several (at least mlocate and GNU findutils, I don't know if slocate is still around).